# How to add the image to Image View

Tags: android, android-view

I want to add the custom view to the Image View I tried but i am not getting. please can anybody help me.

Code:

```
View view = stduiesAdapter.getView(arg2, arg1, arg0);                   
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
ivImageDrag.setImageBitmap(bm);//Here ivImageDrag is the Image View
```

**Problem:** Here I am getting the bitmap value is null.

Comment: Have you tried: ivImageDrag.invalidate();

Comment: Just set it in the view background

Comment: No.But In the above code bitmap returns null then what is the use of invalidate().

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

Assign a global variable,

```
View view=null;
```

Add this to your onCreate()

```
view = stduiesAdapter.getView(arg2, arg1, arg0);                   
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
```

And now override this method,

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
ivImageDrag.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

This is where your view gets drawn. So only at this point you will get a value for Bitmap.